# Objects are created without intention

Tags: java, object, iterator

I am trying to create a LinkedList and then create a menu asking to create a Teacher, Show Teacher list.
The thing is that I can create the Teacher object and add it to the LinkedList, but, when I select the Second option, Show Teacher List more than one time without creating a new Teacher, the programs continue to creating objects.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Teacher> teacher = new LinkedList();
    int id, salary,op;
    String name, programm, teacherList ="";

    Teacher t1 = new Teacher();

    op=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, pick an option: \n"
            + "1. Add Teacher. \n"
            + "2. Get Teacher List. \n"
    ));

    while(op!=0){
        if(op == 1){
            id=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese ID del docente: "));
            name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre del docente: ");
            programm=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese programa del docente: ");
            salary=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese salario del docente: "));
            Teacher d = new Teacher(id,name,programm,salary);
            teacher.add(d);
        }else if(op == 2){
            Iterator p = teacher.iterator();
            while(p.hasNext()){
                teacherList = teacherList + "\n"+ p.next();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, teacherList);
        }
        op=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, pick an option: \n"
            + "1. Add Teacher. \n"
            + "2. Get Teacher List. \n"
            ));
    }

}
```

}

Class Teacher:

```
public class Teacher {
private int id;
private String name;
private String programm;
private int salary;

public Teacher() {
}

public Teacher(int id, String name, String programm, int salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name= name;
    this.programm = programm;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}

public String getProgramm() {
    return programm;
}

public void setProgramm(String programm) {
    this.programm = programm;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String message;
    message = "Id: "+this.id+" - Name: "+this.name+" - Programm: "+this.programm+" - Salary: $"+this.salary;
    return message;
}
```

}

Comment: Isaac - Any update?

Comment: This worked for me. Thank You very much my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the objects are duplicated, it's that you are adding the new text to the teacherList variable without clearing it.
So after (or before)

```
while(p.hasNext()){
    teacherList = teacherList + "\n"+ p.next();
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, teacherList);
```

You should probably add something like

```
teacherList = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

While navigating the list, you need to add the string representation of each teacher (`toString()`) to a string and display the string once you have iterated the whole list.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Teacher> teachers = new LinkedList();
        int id, salary, op;
        String name, programm, teacherList = "";

        Teacher teacher;

        op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Please, pick an option: \n" + "1. Add Teacher. \n" + "2. Get Teacher List. \n"));

        while (op != 0) {
            if (op == 1) {
                id = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese ID del docente: "));
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre del docente: ");
                programm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese programa del docente: ");
                salary = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese salario del docente: "));
                teacher = new Teacher(id, name, programm, salary);
                teachers.add(teacher);
            } else if (op == 2) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (Teacher t : teachers) {
                    sb.append(t.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
            }
            op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Please, pick an option: \n" + "1. Add Teacher. \n" + "2. Get Teacher List. \n"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I've used a `StringBuilder` variable instead of a `String` variable to collect the string representation of each teacher to avoid too many strings getting created. If you wish to use a `String` variable for it, you can do so.
2. I've used enhanced `for` loop to navigate the list (`teachers`). If you wish to use `Iterator` for it, you can do so.

**A sample output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try add `teacherList = ""` after `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, teacherList);`